# How to implement multilevel inheritance using design pattern

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

I had previously implemented Abstract Factory Pattern on simple problems and it worked. So I tried to use same thing to solve this problem but I was confused. I wrote the bottom level classes but confused how to combine them to a single program. What Should I do and How should it be done?

I am using Java to write a code to calculate tax. I am having base class `TaxPayer`. Taxpayer can have multiple `incomeSource`. There can be many types of `TaxPayer` or `IncomeSource`. There can be many income headings for different income sources as its attributes, which will be stored in database. The tax rate will be different for different taxpayer type and amount of `taxableIncome`.

Base class Taxpayer is defined as

```
public abstract class TaxPayer {
    private List<IncomeSource> incomeSource;
    double taxRate;
    Address address;
    other attributes here;

    public Double getTaxRate(){
        return 0.25; //default tax rate
    }
}

public abstract class IncomeSource {
    private String incomeSourceName;
    private Double incomeHeading1, incomeHeading2, incomeHeading3;
    private Double totalIncome = incomeHeading1 + incomeHeading2 + incomeHeading3;
}
```

There can be more levels of `IncomeSource` inheritance with different income headings. Similarly tax payer type can be modeled into following inheritance structure

```
Base Class: Taxpayer
    * IndividualPerson
        * Male, Female, OldAge
    * Business
        * Bank, ITIndustry, HydroElectricIndustry
    * TaxFree
        * SocialOrganization, ReligiousOrganization, PoliticalParty etc.
```

The subclasses of `TaxPayer` generally modifies the `taxRate` to be applied to `taxableIncome` and sometimes changes `taxableIncome` with some logic. For an example:

```
abstract class IndividualPerson extends TaxPayer{
    if (incomeSource.taxableIncome > 250000) taxRate = ratex;
    if (incomeSource.taxableIncome > 500000) taxRate = ratey;
    @override
    public getTaxRate() {
        return taxRate;
    }
}
class Female extends IndividualPerson {
    if (incomeSource.getNumberOfIncomeSource() > 1) taxRate = taxRate + rate1;
    else taxRate = taxRate - rate2
    if (address.isRural() = true) taxRate = taxRate - rate3;
    if (attributeX = true) taxRate = taxRate + rate4;
    if ("Some other attribute" = true) taxableIncome = taxableIncome - someAmount;
}
```

We have to check other attributes of `Taxpayer` and `IncomeSource` to determine the `taxRate`. Mostly, `taxRate` is different for different logic, but sometimes, `taxableIncome` can be discounted.

I am trying return tax rate according to TaxPayer type and taxableIncome. I am confused how to combine bottom level classes together.

Comment: Why do you have such a complex hierarchy - for example how does having a `Male` and `Female` `Taxpayer` classes add anything? I think you need to rethink your classes - you need to consider when you can have a parameter. [Effective Java](http://uet.vnu.edu.vn/~chauttm/e-books/java/Effective.Java.2nd.Edition.May.2008.3000th.Release.pdf)(large pdf)  Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance. For example in your `Male`/`Female` case use an `enum`.

Comment: Male and Female will have different tax rates. So I thought it would be better to have those. How could it be changed to composition rather than inheritance?

Comment: That could be fixed by adding a taxrate variable. If you try and depict every variable as a hierarchy you will end up with a mess. Hierarchies should be used to change _behaviour_ rather than _state_.

Comment: So, replacing getTaxRate() by Double taxRate should be the correct way to do it?

Comment: I think I will have little more complex logic in `Male`, `Female` and other classes inheriting `TaxPayer` class. I wanted polymorphism with inheritance. Could it be achieved with `enum`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Taxpayer` as a `parent interface` and the three below in the hierarchy will implement it. This `taxpayer` interface will have a `getTaxRate()` method which needs to be implemented by all of the child classes.

You can make the `business` class as another interface extending the parent `taxpayer` interface and make the `bank,hydroelectricity` class extend the `business` interface.

each of the `bank,hydroelectricity` etc will have a `final float` with desired tax rate.

*Suppose A is a person class who has business in Bank* so in that case

```
A implements Bank
```

This will provide the taxrate specific to bank at A.

But better option would be to have the `bank,hydroelectricity` etc as `ENUMS` under `business` class that shall implement the `Taxpayer` interface.

**Better approach**

```
public enum Business {
        BANK(10.1), ITINDUSTRY(8.1), HYDROELECTRICITY(1.3);
        private float value;

        private Business(int value) {
           this.value = value;
        public float getTaxRate(){
           return this.value;
        }
};   

class A implements TaxPayer{
     public String occupation = "BANK";

    //implemented from parent taxpayer 
    public float getTaxRate(){
        return Business.BANK.getTaxRate();
    }
}
```

And if the segregation under taxpayer is not important then you can club all the lowest level classes under a single ENUM.

Do something like above. Hope it gives you a clearer idea.

Comment: I don't think this is at all correct. `taxRate` is a variable rather than a behaviour - using a class hierarchy for this is not the correct approach.

Comment: Agreed using the hierarchy is not an approach favorable thats why I have suggested to use ENUMS in the end . I have explained it as hierarchy too as the person asking the question wanted to model it that way.Atleast thats what i understood from the question.

Comment: I do not want to do it in certain way, but the best way. My question might be formatted incorrectly

Comment: Thank you for the example. I might have little more complex logic to calculate tax rate. Also the inheritance level may go further down. Could this be achieved with `enum`?

Comment: can you put the logic in your question with an example of what you are trying to do. In the ENUMS you can put the factors specific to that profession so while getting taxrate you can call suitable ENUMS and make use of the values the ENUMS correspond to get the net tax rate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59881/discussion-between-prabhu-and-sumeet-sharma).